# Calling a Method With Parameters In Another Class

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods, int

I'm having trouble passing a method with a parameter to another class.

In my main class I declare:

```
searchMap search = new searchMap();
    search.search(null, 0);
```

In my other class, I have that as:

```
public boolean search(int[][] map, int fuel)
{
    int totalSum = 0;
    int row[] = new int[map.length];

    boolean valid = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < map.length; j++)
        {
            if (i == j)
                continue;
            valid = valid && possiblePath(map, fuel, 0, i, j);
        }
    }

    if(totalSum <= fuel)
    {
        System.out.println("This map is solvable :)");
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("This map is NOT solvable :(");
        return false;
    } 
}
```

And I keep getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at searchMap.search(searchMap.java:33)
    at loadMap.load(loadMap.java:117)
    at loadMap.main(loadMap.java:23)
```

I've tried everything and can't break from the NullPointerException. I've tried calling other ints, I've tried calling map[][], and I've had no success. Help would be greatly appreciated!!

EDIT:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        loadMap load = new loadMap();
        load.load();
    }

    public void load()
    {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        Scanner readLine = null;

        if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
        File selectedFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        try {
            readLine = new Scanner(selectedFile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int setMapSize = 0;

        int i;
        int j;
        int toNode;
        int edge;
        setMapSize = readLine.nextInt();
        readLine.nextLine();
        int rowCounter = 0;
        int[][] map = new int[setMapSize][setMapSize];
        int[] row = new int[setMapSize];
        int sum = 0;
        int totalSum = 0;

        System.out.println("MAP: " + map.length);

        do
        {
            String line = readLine.nextLine();
            Scanner newLine = new Scanner(line);

            do
            {
                toNode = newLine.nextInt();
                edge = newLine.nextInt();
                map[rowCounter][toNode] = edge;

            } while(newLine.hasNextInt());

            rowCounter++;
            newLine.close();

        } while (rowCounter < setMapSize);

        int fuel = readLine.nextInt();


        System.out.println("Fuel: " + fuel);
        readLine.close();


        }

        searchMap search = new searchMap();
        search.search(null, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in a null map, then turning around and calling this line.. map will be null and you are unable to call .length on a null.

```
int row[] = new int[map.length];
```

You could fix this by adding a check to make sure the parameter map is not null

```
public boolean search(int[][] map, int fuel) {
    boolean valid = false;

    if (map != null) {
        int totalSum = 0;
        int row[] = new int[map.length];    
        for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < map.length; j++) {
                if (i == j) continue;
                valid = valid && possiblePath(map, fuel, 0, i, j);
            }
        }

        if (totalSum <= fuel) {
            System.out.println("This map is solvable :)");
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("This map is NOT solvable :(");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return valid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling:

```
search.search(null, 0);
```

so you pass `null` as the map parameter..

Which will cause NullPointerException starting here since a `null` does not have a length property:

```
int row[] = new int[map.length];
```

You need to pass in your map instead of passing a null value. Providing your SearchMap class would probably help.

Now that I see you're declaring map:

```
int[][] map = new int[setMapSize][setMapSize];
```

Then when you want to pass in the map to the search function, you should call

```
search.search(map, 0);
```

`int[][]` is the **type** of the **variable** `map`, so there is no need to use `[][]` when using the variable.

You also declared `map` inside the `if` so it's out of scope by the time you call it for search.
I think you want to move it inside that if statement since you don't want to search when there's no file.

```
if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
{
    // ...
    int[][] map = new int[setMapSize][setMapSize];
    // ...

    searchMap search = new searchMap();
    search.search(map, 0);
}
```

Comment: @HowbeitGirl Please show what you tried. I imagine that your SearchMap class internally stores a map, so you'd need to pass that into the parameter or just reference that directly in your method. It would help to see how you've designed your SearchMap.

Comment: mapLoad does, searchMap is supposed to pull the data (which is under the method I shared, search()...) from loadMap and tell the user if it's solvable or not. Give me a second.

Comment: How I typed it out (three different ways): search.search(map[][], fuel]; search.search(int map[][], int fuel); search.search(map[][], 0);

Comment: @HowbeitGirl Now that I can see how you declared map, I've updated my answer.

Comment: @HowbeitGirl Oh, you declared map inside the `if`. Updated answer.

Comment: I ran out of time to try implementing this. I'll update this in a couple of hours. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

it is because you put null in for the map. 
null is normally fine as a placeholder but when you do things like:

```
 map.length
```

you are asking for a property of a null value. 
null values have no properties.
try putting a test map in instead.

Answer (score 0):

A null pointer exception occurs probably means that you are trying to **access** something which **doesn't exist.**

In this case, your `int[][] map is null` and in the 2nd line of you search method, you are trying to get the `map.length`. Make any sense to you? Java is unable to get the length of an array which does not exist, thus giving your the `nullPointerException`.

You can solve your problem by either:

1. Pass in an array reference instead of null when calling your method.

**Do this in your main:**

```
searchMap search = new searchMap();
int[][] map = new int [5][5];   //Just an example
search.search(map, 0);          //Pass in an existing 2D array instead of null
```

### OR

2. Add a check to see whether array is null

**You can do it as below:**

```
    if (map== null)
       length = 0;
    else 
       length = map.length;      
   int row[] = new int[length];
```

---

Personally, as a habit, I will also suggest your refrain from using similar names for methods and objects.